How to calculate the torque disturbance of an unbalanced flywheel?
I would like to understand how an unbalance of a flywheel affects the dynamics of a simplified mechanical model.
Assuming that the mechaincal dynamics can be modeled as (neclecting inertia of the shaft)
\begin{align}
       (J_m+J_F) \frac{d\omega_m}{dt} = T_e - T_d
     \end{align}
with:
\begin{align}
 w_m: \text{angular velocity of the rotor and flywheel}\newline
J_m: \text{Inertia Motor}\newline
J_F: \text{Inertia Flywheel}\newline
T_e: \text{Torque of Motor}\newline
T_d: \text{Disturbance Torque}\newline
     \end{align}
The inertia of the rotor can be modeled with a solid cylinder and the flywheel as a hollow cylinder (which is magically fixed to the rotor ;) ).
As shown on the figure, an additional mass should be placed at the outer part of the flywheel.
The question is how this disturbance can be modeled (ideally by the disturbance torque T_d)
as a function of the mechanical speed and most probably as a function of the mechanical position.
Could it be, that the disturbance force F_d can be calculated by
\begin{align}
       F_d = m_d l_3 w_m^2 \text{sin}(w_m t)
     \end{align}
with
\begin{align}
m_d: \text{mass of disturbance}\newline
l_3: \text{length from rotor centre to centre of disturbance mass}\newline
     \end{align}

For example:
In the following paper (DOI:10.1109/ICA.2011.6130125):
"Disturbance reduction on the small satellite actuator"
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254047229_Disturbance_reduction_on_the_small_satellite_actuator
The force is defined as:


Is it possible to multiply this force by the radius to obtain the disturbance torque?

An unbalance does not create a torque in a simple 2 dof model.

Hi Greg, do you have any idea how to consider this unbalance for a mechanical model of the motor? Could it be modeled by a position dependent Inertia or a more complex mechanical model?

Yes, it generates a rotating radial vector of force in the bearings locating the flywheel.
